# tricky subtraction on the same column

Tags: sql

I have a table named "prices" with 3 fields, one for country, one for the price and one for the date.

I need to make a difference between the price of each country in determined date.

i was making this code, and it works, but is making a substraction of each value on the first column, against each value on the other.

```
SELECT c1.value1-c2.value2 AS DIFERENCIAL
FROM     (
 SELECT PRICE AS value1 
 FROM PRICES_TABLE WHERE P = 'GERMANY' 
 AND (FECHA BETWEEN '17/01/2016' AND '17/01/2016')
) AS c1,
(
 SELECT PRICES AS value2 
 FROM PRICES_TABLE WHERE P = 'PANAMA' 
 AND (FECHA BETWEEN '17/01/2016' AND '17/01/2016')
) AS c2
```

Is not what i want, if i have the values of lets say 23 values for today, and its country have assigned 23 values, i want vale1, value2.... value23 of the first column to be subtracred with value1...value23 on the second column.
Instead, is making c1.value1-c2.value1, c1.vale1-c2.value2... c1.value1-c2.value23, c1.value2-c2.value, c1,value2-c2.value2... c1.value2-c2.value23 etc.

Any idea?

Comment: You need an ordering on the prices within a date.  Does `fecha` have a time component?  Do you have another column that specifies the matching criterion?

Comment: i have a different column for hours actually

Comment: But I thought you only had 3 columns? You need a way to join each row in one table to one and only one row in the other table. To do that, you need something that uniquely identifies the rows that need to be joined.

Comment: Also, it would help if you told us which RDBMS you're using.

Comment: Your `join` is missing an `on` clause.

Comment: sorry i lost my connection during the weekend. thanks everybody for your answers, Gordon Linoff got it right :B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use conditional aggregation or a `join` approach.  So, this is one method:

```
SELECT ptg.fecha, ptg.hours, (ptg.prices - ptp.prices) AS DIFERENCIAL
FROM (SELECT pt.* 
      FROM PRICES_TABLE pt
      WHERE P = 'GERMANY' AND FECHA = '2016-01-17' 
     ) ptg JOIN
     (SELECT pt.*
      FROM PRICES_TABLE pt
      WHERE P = 'PANAMA' AND FECHA = '2016-01-17'
     ) ptp
     ON ptg.fecha = ptp.fecha and ptg.hours = ptp.hours;
```